# Convert string with multiple full names into names with first character surname

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a string with multiple names and an optional 'et al' at the end of the string to a string with name and first character of each surnames.

To make it easier to understand:

```
Name Firstname, name firstname secondname et al
Name Firstname, name firstname secondname, et al
Name Firstname,name firstname secondname,et al
Name Firstname, name firstname secondname, et al.
Name Firstname,     name     firstname     secondname,   et   al.
Name F., name firstn. sec., et al.
Name F, name f s, et al.
```

...should all result in:

```
Name F, Name FS et al.
```

So this is what I'm using so far, but the first example fails as the last comma is missing.

I the first step has to be extracting the optional 'et al' string. After this, the split makes sense...

And maybe someone has an idea to make the code a bit easier:

```
const names = string.split(',')
const etal = names[names.length - 1].indexOf('et al') !== -1 && names.pop().trim()

const condensed = names.map(function (name) {
  return name.trim().split(' ').reduce(function (r, part, index) {
    return index ? r + part[0].toUpperCase() : part + ' '
  }, '')
})

etal && condensed.push('et al.')
return condensed.join(', ').trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be better solution but I came up with the following:

```js
var names = [
  "Name Firstname,name firstname secondname,et al",
  "Name Firstname, name firstname secondname, et al.",
  "Name Firstname,     name     firstname     secondname,   et   al.",
  "Name F., name firstn. sec., et al.",
  "Name F, name f s, et al."
];
var nameRes = names.map(function(name){
  nameTemp = name.split(',');
  let res = "";
  nameTemp.forEach(function(n, i){
    if(i==0){
      res = n.split(' ')[0] + " " + n.split(' ')[1].charAt(0);
    }
    if(i==1){
      n = n.split(' ').filter(j=>j!=="");
      var n1 = n[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + n[0].slice(1);
      var n2 = (n[1].charAt(0) + n[2].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
      n = n1+' '+n2
      res += ', ' + n;
    }
    if(i==2){
      res += ' ' + n.split(' ').filter(j=>j!=="").join(' ');
    }
  });
  
  return res;
});
console.log(nameRes);
```

Comment: @user3142695, You didn't mention any specific condition. I tried to provide a solution based on the input you have provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm talking about the input examples provided in the post. The first input example wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @user3142695, yes you are right. But you have to have some kind of token in your string to operate on them dynamically.

Comment: Would it be an option to use a regex to get rid of the 'et al' string at the end of the string - if it is existing? And then go on...

Comment: @user3142695, if you want to replace `et al` from string you can simply use `replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach your using is lengthy and (difficult to read, because you are chaining function calls) I would use a Regular Expression to rid the elements you desire.  The Regular Expression would then look something like this you could first get rid of extra spaces and "FirstName, " and " name "

```
string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/g , " ");
string.replace(/FirstName, | name /g, "");
```

That leaves you with 
Name firstname, secondname, et al

then you would write another Regular Expression like

```
let set = /\B .+ .+\B(?=, et al\b)/g;
```

then

```
string.replace( set, "");
```

For a more thorough discussion of Regular Expressions visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

You could also combine all the steps but that makes Regular Expressions ridiculously difficult to read and decipher what is going on. Regular Expressions are built for doing these kinds of replacements with fewer lines of code. Instead of chaining function calls you have 3 or 4 calls to string replace if you do it in steps makes the code a lot easier to read. This doesn't account for all the inconsistencies but hopefully you get the general idea.